# Buscar 3 resultados da mesma tabela agrupadas pelo mesmo id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a `tbl_ocorrencias` que regista ocorrências de um determinada viatura. Ou seja, a tabela é composta pelo seguinte:

```
- tbl_ocorrencias -
   id_ocorrencia
   id_viatura
   data
   hora
```

Neste caso, uma ocorrência só tem uma viatura mas uma viatura pode ter vários ocorrências.

O que pretendo está na imagem seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está na imagem é o seguinte:

- Só posso ir buscar as últimas 3 ocorrências de uma determinada `id_viatura`
- Cada ocorrência encontrada é listada numa coluna a frente como aparece na imagem

Para isto estou a tentar fazer em php e mysql mas não estou a conseguir chegar a uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ocorrencias GROUP BY id_viatura ORDER BY data, hora DESC",$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id_viatura = $row['id_viatura'];
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ocorrencias WHERE id_viatura = '$id_viatura' ORDER BY data, hora DESC LIMIT 3",$conn);
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) 
    {
        if($id_viatura_velho != $id_viatura)
        {
            $outstr.= "\n";
        }
        $outstr.= $row1['id_viatura'].";".$row1['data'].";".$row['hora'].";";
        $id_viatura_velho = $row1['id_viatura'];

    }
}
```

O `\n` representa mudança de linha e o `;` mudança de coluna. Foi assim que resolvi a minha questão